# Remove extra space added by Diacritic

Tags: spacing

I have two separate lines over two separate words, but I want to have the line at the same distance over these words. I have to use however a Diacritic over one of those two words, which causes the line to be a bit further away from that word. Do visualize that I have made the image showing the effect I mean. What I want now, is to get the bottom line of the two E's to the sme distance from the dotted line.

How can I do that?
[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Byington}
\usepackage{dashrule} % make dashed line

\def\signature#1#2{
\parbox[b]{0.5cm}{\smash{#1}\vskip4mm}
\hfill 
\parbox[t]{0.5cm}{\shortstack{\hdashrule[0.5ex]{0.5cm}{0.5pt}{0.5pt}\\\small#2}}
}
\def\sigskip{\vskip0.4in plus 0.1in}
        \def\beginskip{\vskip0.5875in plus 0.1in}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c @{\hskip 0.005cm} c }
  \signature{}{{\fontsize{2.5mm}{0em}\selectfont E}} & \signature{}{{\fontsize{2.5mm}{0em}\selectfont \"{E}}} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for getting the picture?

Comment: As always here, post a MWE showing your issue.

Comment: It's quite unclear why the dotted line should be half a centimeter wide; usually signatures require more space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\vphantom{\"E}` in the definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{dashrule} % make dashed line

\def\signature#1#2{
\parbox[b]{0.5cm}{\smash{#1}\vskip4mm}
\hfill
\parbox[t]{0.5cm}{\shortstack{\hdashrule[0.5ex]{0.5cm}{0.5pt}{0.5pt}\\\small#2\vphantom{\"E}}}
}
\def\sigskip{\vskip0.4in plus 0.1in}
        \def\beginskip{\vskip0.5875in plus 0.1in}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c @{\hskip 0.005cm} c }
  \signature{}{{\fontsize{2.5mm}{0em}\selectfont E}} & \signature{}{{\fontsize{2.5mm}{0em}\selectfont \"{E}}} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adding a `\strut` as `....\\\small#2\strut}}` works too.